# How can I add the user of an application to the group of another application?

Tags: root-access, linux, shell, file-permissions, busybox

I'd like to add the user of one application to the group of another so that I can read the other applications private content without doing a `su` every time.

I can't find the `adduser` or the `useradd` command on my device running Cyanogenmod. It doesn't seem to be a part of the busybox that came bundled with Cyanogenmod.

Since the Android follows a very different permission system from Linux, I'm wondering it is in possible to do this and if so how can I get the `useradd` or the `adduser` commands.